# Strings and appending in Python

Tags: python, string, append

In Python a string is immutable. I find the function `string.join()` could add the value to a string but it seems the following doesn't work.

```
#coding: utf-8
if __name__ == "__main__":
    str = "A fox has jumped into the river"
    tmp = ""
    for i in str:
        tmp = tmp.join(i)
    print tmp
```

I expect the output should be "A fox has jumped into the river", but it output the "r"
why?

Is there any similar methods which is something like `string.append()`?

Comment: You getting this result because iterating through string makes your ``i`` - on of each symbol in that string. And so when loop comes to last iteration - `i` becomes last symbol of the string - `'r'`. `join()` is the method of string object, which joins sequence elements, provided as argument, separated by object to which this method bounded. In your case you joining sequence (string) with one element `'r'` with separator `''` - and you getting result - `'r'`

Comment: Also fastest way to join strings is is `''.join([str1, str2])`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a = "pp"
>>> b = "kk"
>>> a += b
>>> a
'ppkk'
```

Comment: Any other questions? I don't know why you didn't accept any answers as correct. If you have more question about that, leave here lol.

Comment: @python sir? are you here?

Answer (score 3):

You can append simply by using `+`:

```
tmp = tmp + i
```

which can be combined with an in-place addition assignment:

```
tmp += i
```

but this is not nearly as efficient as joining the *whole* sequence with `''.join()`:

```
str = "A fox has jumped into the river"
tmp = ''.join(str)
```

The latter is of course, rather pointless, as we just took all individual characters of `str`, and rejoined them into a new, otherwise equal, string. But it is *far* more efficient than calling `+` in a loop, as `.join()` only has to create a new string *once*, while a loop with `+` creates new strings for each concatenation.

It gets more interesting when you use a delimiter:

```
>>> ' - '.join(str)
'A -   - f - o - x -   - h - a - s -   - j - u - m - p - e - d -   - i - n - t - o -   - t - h - e -   - r - i - v - e - r'
```

The thing to note here is that you call `.join()` on the delimiter string, *not* on the sequence you are about to join!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> '-'.join('a')
'a'
```

`str.join` doesn't work like that. That's the reason why `"r"` is the output, since at the end of the for loop you have set `tmp = tmp.join('r')` whichc will just result in `"r"`.

This is how `str.join` is usually used:

```
>>> '-'.join('abc')
'a-b-c'
```

or

```
>>> ', '.join(['foo', 'bar', 'spam'])
'foo, bar, spam'
```

You want simple string concatenation

```
tmp = ""
for i in str:
    tmp += i
```

or use a list and `''.join` for [efficient string concatenation](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) (the former solution is O(N^2) due to the immutable nature of strings)

```
tmp = []
for i in str:
    tmp.append(i)
tmp = ''.join(tmp)
```

(`''.join` joins the list into a string with an empty string as a separator)

One last note: don't use `str` as a variable name, it's a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want i think:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    str = "A fox has jumped into the river"
    tmp = ""
    for i in str:
        tmp += i
    print (tmp)
```

The reason you code doesn't work is that join joins all the tokens in the list you are providing, seperated by whatever string you "apply" it to. It doesn't actually append to a string.